# Закрывается ли сам по себе объект _io.TextIOWrapper?

Tags: python, io

При записи/чтении данных из файлов используется либо open с последующим присвоением io объекта, обработкой, и последующем закрытием, или же тот же open, только в качестве менеджера контекста, как пример:

```
a = open('example.txt', 'r') # открыли файл
print(a) # результат вывода - <_io.TextIOWrapper name=.......>
a.close() # закрываем файловый объект
###
with open('example.txt', 'r') as b: # открыли файл
    print(b) # результат вывода - <_io.TextIOWrapper name=.......>
# закрывать файловый объект вручную не требуется, данная процедура происходит 
# при автоматическом вызове __exit__ метода
```

Вопрос:
что насчёт остальных примеров открытия?
Закрываются ли в такие моменты файловые объекты сами по себе, или так и остаются висеть(???) открытыми

```
lines = [line for line in open('example.txt', 'r').readlines()]
print(lines)
```

Comment: Все внешние ресурсы нужно всегда закрывать явно (через close или with). В общем случае нет никакой гарантии, что `__del__` у объектов будет вызван и файлы будут закрыты, поэтому последний пример стоит считать неправильным - в частности, в PyPy этот файл останется открыт навечно

Comment: (хотя ладно, не совсем навечно: при сборке мусора файл будет всё-таки закрыт, но произойдёт это неизвестно когда (и произойдёт ли вообще) и сборщик мусора матюкнётся предупреждением "unclosed file")